# Error on filling a gridview based on the values of a dataview from a different table with no direct FK's

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, dataview

I have these tables:

```
TABLE_DIRECTOR
-directorID
-name
-adres
-birthDate
-yearsExperience

TABLE_FILM
-filmID
-directorID
-filmstudioID
-title
-budget
-filmstudioName
-directorName

TABLE_FILMSTUDIO
-filmstudioID
-name
-website
-foundingDate
-numberOfBuildings
```

What I'm trieng to do is fill a `detailsview` with all the `filmdirectors`. I also have a `gridview` which is filled with all the `filmstudio`'s the `directors` have worked with.

To fill this `gridview` I've put the following code in my `TABLE_FLMSTUDIO_TABLEADAPTER`:

```
SELECT TABLE_FILMSTUDIO.filmstudioID, TABLE_FILMSTUDIO.name,
  TABLE_FILMSTUDIO.website, TABLE_FILMSTUDIO.foundingDate,
  TABLE_FILMSTUDIO.numberOfBuildings
FROM TABLE_FILMSTUDIO INNER JOIN
  TABLE_FILM ON TABLE_FILMSTUDIO.filmstudioID = TABLE_FILM.filmstudioID
WHERE (TABLE_FILM.directorID = @directorID)
```

However this is giving me following error when I run the page

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Does Table_Film contain filmstudioID ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: TABLE_FILM -filmID -directorID -title -budget -filmstudioName -directorName does not contains 
filmstudioID but you are using it in INNER JOIN as TABLE_FILM.filmstudioID.

Secondly, the error says that one of your table contains repeating data. ( violating foreign keys )

Comment: Thanks, TABLE_FILM does containt the filmstudioID but I forgot to write it in here, I edited it. I'll hava a look at the repeating data, thanks in advance